# Intellij plugin Fortran

Tags: intellij-idea, fortran, intellij-plugin

I have installed Intellij IDEA Version 2017.1.4 and installed the Fortran plugin. However, I don't see an option of starting a Fortran project even after restarting IntelliJ. I see the plugin has been successfully installed though.

Is there a simple hello-world fortran example with Intellij?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't create a Fortran project in Intellij IDEA. You can use [cmake](https://cmake.org/%22cmake%22) to build you project and import such project in [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/working-with-cmake.html). [Here](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMakeForFortranExample) you can find some information about compiling Fortran project with CMake. Also several example projects can be easily found in the Internet.

General idea behind this is that IDE is not a build tool, so you are building your project with build tools and we are doing our best to support build tool that you're using. For now from all JetBrains IDEs only CLion supports build tool that is capable of compiling Fortran project (CMake). In the future CLion will support other build tools capable of doing this ([make](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-494) for example).

Answer (score 0):

JetBrains just released a new [Fortran plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9699-fortran) you may be interested in.  I tried it in IntelliJ 15 and it did not allow me to create a new Fortran project.  I have NOT tried it in CLion yet.